# MySQL table not working after a few days of use

Tags: mysql, locking, deadlock, blocking, orm

I have the following tables on *MySQL* server, *5.5.46*:

```
CREATE TABLE `locking` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `origin` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `system` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `filename` (`filename`,`origin`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=74882007 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `locking_rules` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timeout` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `origin` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I have the following SQL which is executed periodically from different machines (simultaneously or not):

`DELETE l FROM locking l,locking_rules r WHERE l.origin=r.origin AND r.name!='*' AND ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(l.timestamp,NOW())))>r.timeout`

In this table there are permanently inserted new rows. The table is in general at about 20000 rows size. I insert on DB using *OpenJPA* ORM, and remove using the provided "native query".

**The problem:**

Sometimes, once at few days, delete queries on `locking` table are just waiting and nothing happens anymore to this table. **Can anybody give me some hints on which part should I look in order to see where the problem sits?**

If I run `show engine INNODB status`, output doesn't have anything related to `locking` table locks or deadlocks.

Comment: Try to rename the table `unlock`... sorry bad joke

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is that you are scanning most of 20K rows and locking the rows to be deleted as you go.  The scan, itself, is time consuming.

If you are using MyISAM, that is a big issue -- switch to InnoDB.

Don't use `TIMEDIFF`, it will get you in trouble for large differences.  I will assume that `l.timestamp` was some time in the past and that `r.timeout` is how many seconds before it "times out".

```
DELETE  l
    FROM  locking l,
          locking_rules r
    WHERE  l.origin = r.origin
      AND  r.name!='*'
      AND  l.timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL r.timeout SECOND
    LIMIT 100
```

And have

```
l: INDEX(origin, timestamp)
```

If the `DELETE` is running too slowly, either increase the frequency of running it, or increase the `LIMIT`.  But I would not use more than 1000.

OK, the `LIMIT` will probably spit at you.  So, I'll provide another possibility:

```
DELETE  l
    FROM  locking l,
    JOIN  ( SELECT l2.id
              FROM locking l2
              JOIN locking_rules r  ON r.origin = l.origin
                                   AND l.timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL r.timeout SECOND
              WHERE r.name!='*'
              LIMIT 100
           ) s  ON s.id = l.id;
```

But this will also suffer from scanning too much of `locking` to find the few rows that need deleting.

So, let's start over and break the task into two steps:

1. Find 100 `ids` to delete.  This is just a `SELECT`, so it has much less impact.
2. Delete those 100 (or fewer) via the `PRIMARY KEY` -- This is *much* less invasive.

thus:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t
    SELECT l2.id
      FROM locking l2
      JOIN locking_rules r  ON r.origin = l.origin
                           AND l.timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL r.timeout SECOND
      WHERE r.name!='*'
      LIMIT 100;
DELETE  l, t
    WHERE l.id = t.id;
```

Let's prevent the various connections from doing the "same" code at the "same" time.  (In pseudo client code:)

```
if (GET_LOCK('messy delete) == 1)
{
    perform the above code
    RELEASE_LOCK('messy delete');
}
```

It *may* be that the sporadic hangup is due to two `DELETEs` stumbling over each other, perhaps even having a 'domino effect' cascading into other connections.